# Why is adb not detecting more than 5 devices?

Tags: android, adb, centos7

I have adb installed on CentOS 7.9, but for some strange reason it is not detecting more than 5 devices.  lsusb was able to see all the devices connected.  If I unplug some devices and plug in the previously undetected device, it will show the device in the adb devices list, but then when I reconnect the original devices, one of them won't be detected and adb will only show total 5 devices.

```
[sttools@softtestmini02 ~]$ adb devices
List of devices attached
454446454d453098        device
R5CRC2H8EDM     device
RFCR103PDCY     device
RFCR10E7PQA     device
RFCR60XDSHY     device
```

Comment: I have a CentOS 7.9 development machine that has been able to see more than 5 devices. The first thing to try is: "adb stop-server; sudo adb start-server" to make sure the adb server is running as root, which is much more reliable. If that doesn't fix it, look at your lsusb results to see if there's any correlation between usb buses and visibility gto adb?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found out the problem was a USB endpoint limitation.  Basically, the USB host controller only supports a certain amount of endpoints.